# Get the number of unread emails from default email provider in Android

Tags: android, email

Basically what the title says. I'd like to get the number of unread emails so I can toss it on a little badge thing. Gmail is popular, but not everyone uses it, so instead I'd like to do it with the default android email account aggregator application. It doesn't have to work on devices before api v15.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: which protocol are you planning to use in order to chieve this... is it imap???

Comment: I wasn't looking to go that far in depth. I just wanted some kind of emailprovider sort of thing I had hoped would be hidden somewhere in the android APIs. I haven't been able to find anything on google though.